# Laravel routes not working except for root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have been spending hours on this issue and hope to find my way out. I have set up laravel correctly, created a project myapp

My route.php file just contains

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('/users', function()
{
    return 'Users!';
});
```

When I run

```
http://localhost/myapp/public/
```

I get the laravel start page correctly

When I run

```
http://localhost/myapp/public/users
```

I get

```
The requested URL /myapp/index.php was not found on this server.
```

I don't know why its looking for index.php.

When I run

```
http://localhost/myapp/public/index.php/users
```

I get a page with text "Users". I should obtain this page when running

```
http://localhost/myapp/public/users
```

instead.

Below is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    Rewritebase /myapp/
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas? Am running a Apache on Linux.

Comment: Check this [stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)

Answer (score 5):

Your `RewriteBase` is set to `/myapp/` but your index.php file is in `/mayapp/public/` is it not?

As such, I think you'll find the `RewriteBase` needs to be `/myapp/public/`.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, my Laravel app was one level further down in my folder structure, but by judiciously modifying the `index.php` entry file, as well as adding a `RewriteBase` to the `.htaccess` worked wonders.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure you have mod_rewrite enabled on apache web server.
2. Make sure that your vhost config allows and parses htaccess files

Answer (score 1):

Just do this and try to restart the apache.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

To restart apache: `sudo services apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem with production server, nothing seemed to work, no chmod/s no other solution but adding a simple line to .htaccess worked.

```
RewriteBase /
```

Thanks to the thread and user [odaria](https://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-500-internal-server-error-for-all-routes-other-than)

Answer (score 0):

In your application/config/application.php file change:

```
'index' => 'index.php',
```

to:

```
'index' => '',
```

That should tell laravel not to use index.php and to rewrite correctly.

It works with standard .htaccess file which comes with laravel (haven't checked if you modified it)

Comment: This line was not present in app.php. I added it but still same problem.

Comment: You're using laravel 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

Use this re-write rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /my_app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, in `application/config/app.php' change:

`'index' => 'index.php'`

to

`'index' => ''`

Comment: Just a small modification in your answer. RewriteBase should be /myapp, no underscore. There was no index,php entry in my app.php, I just added the line. Now even root path not working getting
URL /myapp/index.php was not found on this server.
Reverted my .htaccess and root path works. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to add a symbolic link in command line:

```
ln -s your/acutal/path/myapp/public app-dev
```

Now browse `http://localhost/app-dev` should work fine as well as all the routes. You can change app-dev to whatever you want as the name.