# How Can I Remove “public/index.php” in the Laravel Url Generated?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I need to remove  `index.php` or `public/index.php` from the generated URL in Laravel; commonly path is `localhost/public/index.php/someWordForRoute`, It should be something like `localhost/someWordForRoute.`

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php[L]
```

**app/config/app.php**

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

How can I change that?

Comment: [Pretty URLs in Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls). Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662378/routes-not-working-without-index-php/21662885#21662885

Comment: @Kryten doesnt work =/

Comment: This is the solution when the other solution doen't work http://www.dev-metal.com/enable-mod_rewrite-ubuntu-14-04-lts/

Comment: Is your document root pointing at the intended folder, i.e `/var/www/project_name/public`

Comment: or you could try moving the files too like this: https://youtu.be/ybJYyU5FPv4

Comment: In Laravel, you need not to remove index.php. It will be automatically removed for you. Just make public folder as the document root.

Comment: Reopen voter: this question is fundamentally misguided, and stems from a misconfiguration of the web server. The only correct solution is to set the document root of the web server to the public directory. All the highest-voted answers here create potential security problems and encourage bad practices, which is why I've marked it as duplicate of a question whose top answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

### Option 1: Use .htaccess

If it isn't already there, create an .htaccess file in the Laravel root directory.
Create a `.htaccess` file your Laravel root directory if it does not exists already. (Normally it is under your `public_html` folder)

Edit the .htaccess file so that it contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now you should be able to access the website without the "/public/index.php/" part.

### Option 2 : Move things in the '/public' directory to the root directory

Make a new folder in your root directory and move all the files and folder except public folder. You can call it anything you want. I'll use "laravel_code".

Next, move everything out of the public directory and into the root folder. It should result in something somewhat similar to this:
[image]

After that, all we have to do is edit the locations in the `laravel_code/bootstrap/paths.php` file and the `index.php` file.

In `laravel_code/bootstrap/paths.php` find the following line of code:

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public',
```

And change them to:

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../',
```

In `index.php`, find these lines:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';     
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

And change them to:

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel_code/bootstrap/autoload.php';     
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel_code/bootstrap/start.php';
```

Source: [How to remove /public/ from URL in Laravel](https://justcode.me/laravel/remove-public-index-php-url-generated-laravel/)

Comment: If you use Debian Linux, don't forget to edit `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` changing from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` where you see the Directory config, `<Directory /var/www/></Directory>` .

Comment: I had only to had the .htaccess file to my root directory to get it working.

Comment: Moving to /root isn't a good advice at all in production mode! There's a reason why the public folder exists

Comment: To ensure the rewrite rules work check that the apache config `<Directory ...` config has `AllowOverride All'` Something like this:

`<Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        **AllowOverride All**
</Directory>`

Comment: What if I have no conf access on hosting?

Comment: @Daenu What is purpose of public folder what problem will removing it will cause on production?

Comment: Hell no. Never ever do that.

Comment: Along with above.htaccess code rename our server.php file from root to index.php.  These both combinations worked for me.  !! thank @Luzan.

Comment: @Luzan Baral I tried this but not working for me. Why not working in my Case. Created `5.2` Project as `BondOnFire`, giving the read write permissions to `Storage` folder, the welcome screen comes. Thn I run `php artisan make:auth`, it works. I create a Folder `Bond` in `BondOnFire` and put all the code in it except public folder. I take out all the code of public folder outside it in BondOnFire directory . Then changed the .htaccess file and restarted serve.when I click on "Register" on the right side of the home screen, it says requested URL not found. Can you please help, what am I missing.

Answer (score 43):

I tried this on Laravel 4.2

Rename the `server.php` in the your Laravel root folder to `index.php` and copy the `.htaccess` file from `/public` directory to your Laravel root folder.

I hope it works

Comment: If the accepted answer by Luazan doesn't work then this will suffice. Although I would make sure to edit the index.php file in the public folder to redirect users out of public if they go straight to that link.

Comment: The js and css files are not loaded anymore from public folder

Comment: @MaHDyfo - why its not secure ? and how ?

Comment: @151291 because .env file ia accessible for everyone visits your site this way. unless you secure your webserver to avoid this.

Answer (score 23):

Don't get confused with other option the snippet below I am using and will be useful for you too.
Put the below htacces in your root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Go to your public directory and put another htaccess file with the code snippet below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Its working... !!!

Laravel Uses below .htaccess

```
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Great: can you tell me what are pros and cons of this method?

Comment: I only edited the .htaccess in root (your first snippet) and that fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: In laravel 9, this is the only option

Answer (score 15):

1) Check whether mod_rewrite is enabled. Go to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` directory and see whether the `rewrite.load` is available. If not, enable it using the command `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.It will enable the rewrite module. If its already enabled, it will show the message `Module rewrite already enabled`.
2)Create a virtual host for public directory so that instead of giving `http://localhost/public/index.php` we will be able to use like that `http://example.com/index.php`. [hence public folder name will be hidded]
3)Then create a .htaccess which will hide the index.php from your url which shoul be inside the root directory (public folder)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Tried your steps. Got no result yet! I don't why is this happening!

Comment: Give the log info so that we can trace the root cause

Comment: Here is the full log file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fhlbej86nqr5qj/laravel.log?dl=0

Comment: worked for me. Dont make the virtual host go straight to the public folder.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me, my `mod_rewrite` was disabled.

Answer (score 13):

HERE ARE SIMPLE STEPS TO REMOVE PUBLIC IN URL (Laravel 5)

1: Copy all files form public folder and past them in laravel root folder

2: Open index.php and  change

From

```
 require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

To

```
 require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

And

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

To

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

In laravel 4  path 2 is `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/start.php';` instead of `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';/app.php`

That is it.

Comment: Are there any other complications regarding other linking from the site?

Comment: That looks like a great solution and simple also. But really, as Haring10 said. Are there any issues with this?

Answer (score 7):

**For Laravel 4 & 5:**

1. Rename `server.php` in your Laravel root folder to `index.php`
2. Copy the `.htaccess` file from `/public` directory to your Laravel *root folder*.

That's it !! :)

Answer (score 5):

This likely has very little to do with Laravel and everything to do with your Apache configs.

Do you have access to your Apache server config? If so, check this out, from the docs:

> In general, you should only use .htaccess files when you don't have
>   access to the main server configuration file. There is, for example, a
>   common misconception that user authentication should always be done in
>   .htaccess files, and, in more recent years, another misconception that
>   mod_rewrite directives must go in .htaccess files. This is simply not
>   the case. You can put user authentication configurations in the main
>   server configuration, and this is, in fact, the preferred way to do
>   things. Likewise, mod_rewrite directives work better, in many
>   respects, in the main server configuration.
>
> ... In general, use of .htaccess files should be avoided when
>   possible. Any configuration that you would consider putting in a
>   .htaccess file, can just as effectively be made in a 
>   section in your main server configuration file.
>
> Source: [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html).

The reason why I mention this first is because it is best to get rid of `.htaccess` completely if you can,and use a `Directory` tag inside a `VirtualHost` tag. That being said, the rest of this is going to assume you are sticking with the `.htaccess` route for whatever reason.

To break this down, a couple things could be happening:

1. I note, perhaps pointlessly, that your file is named `.htacces` in your question. My guess is that it is a typo but on the off chance you overlooked it and it is in fact just missing the second s, this is exactly the sort of minor error that would leave me banging my head against the wall looking for something more challenging.
2. Your server could not be allowing `.htaccess`. To check this, go to your Apache configuration file. In modern Apache builds this is usually not in one config file so make sure you're using the one that points to your app, wherever it exists. Change

   ```
   AllowOverride none
   ```

   to

   ```
   AllowOverride all
   ```

   As a followup, the Apache documents also recommend that, for security purposes, you don't do this for every folder if you are going to go for `.htaccess` for rewriting. Instead, do it for the folders you need to add `.htaccess` to.
3. Do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled? That could be causing the issues. I notice you have the tag at the top `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`. Try commenting out those tags and restart Apache. If you get an error then it is probably because you need to enable `mod_rewrite`:
   [How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Hope this helps. I've named some of the most common issues but there are several others that could be more mundane or unique. Another suggestion on a dev server? Re-install Apache. If possible, do so from a different source with a good tutorial.

Comment: Great catch for apache2 configuration settings, I miss this setting everytime.

Answer (score 5):

Also make sure the Rewrite Engline is turned on after editing the .htaccess file

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Good observation I  was on a new server and actually had to enable it (and add the necessary bits in the apache configuration as well) using this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod-rewrite-for-apache-on-debian-9

Answer (score 2):

You have to perform following steps to do this, which are as follows

- Map your domain upto public folder of your project (i.e. /var/www/html/yourproject/public) (if using linux)
- Go to your public folder edit your `.htaccess` file there

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect non-www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect non-http to https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Remove index.php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

- The last three rules are for if you are directly accessing any route without `https`, it protect that.

Answer (score 2):

create a new file with the name of .htaccess and add below lines will fix it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

I am sure it will be fixed, as I faced this issue multiple times and fixed this way.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel ships with a pretty URL .htaccess already... you should be good to go out of the box...
http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls

Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled and that your home path is set to the public directory of your application.

Comment: I activaded ``mod_rewrite`` and I copied the code that's on that page and still without works

Comment: Make sure in Apache your path is set to the public folder of your application.

Comment: ``ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /home/web-apps/myproject/public``

Comment: Did you restart apache after enabling mod_rewrite?

Comment: I have a folder called ``user`` is the place where I keep photos, also I have a blade file called ``user`` , when I write in the URL ``myproject.com/user`` shows me the contents of the folder, the pictures

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

use this in .htaccess and restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps like it did for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `server.php` in the your Laravel root folder to `index.php` and copy the `.htaccess` file from `/public` directory to your Laravel root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Laravel 5 for a project and there is a file in the root called `server.php`.

Change it to `index.php` and it works or type in terminal:

```
$cp server.php index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use IIS Windows Server add `web.config` file in root folder and put the below code  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^system.*" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and if you use `.htaccess`  use this one :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE NOTE**

when serving a Laravel project with Docker: you won't need to do any of this. Only use this option when your root (or more commonly: public_html) directory of your website is your Laravel project (this is not the case when you're using Docker).

**DON'T!**

YOU REALLY SHOULD NOT rename server.php in your Laravel root folder to index.php and copy the .htaccess file from the /public directory to your Laravel root folder!!!

This way everyone can access some of your files (.env for example). Try it yourself. You don't want that!

**DO**

Instead, you should create an .htaccess file in your root like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will silently rewrite all your base URIs to the /public folder. Even all Headers, for example the HTTP Authorization Header, and all optional URI parameters will silently be passed on to the /public folder as well.

That's all

Comment: Plagiarised from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53516975/1255289

Answer (score 0):

Nginx configuration, you can use the following equivalent configuration

```
location / {
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1 last;
}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(public)/(index.php)/$ $1/$4 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Providesome more explanation to your solution