# How to remove public/index.php from url in laravel 5?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and having one problem when i upload my project on rackspace it is showing public/index.php in the url. Without this my project is not working.

Please help me .

Htacesss of my public is this :-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

With regards
Harpartapsingh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

You do this by making the `/path/to/laravel/public` folder itself your webroot in Apache/nginx instead of `/path/to/laravel`.  With that, and the standard `.htaccess` in the public folder, you should be able to access your routes without the `public` or `index.php` URL segments.

Comment: Rackspace don't allowed my domain to direct redirect to public folder.

Comment: Can you SSH into the server and simply symlink `httpdocs -> public`? i.e. `ln -s public httpdocs`. Assuming your project is **not** inside the doc root (which I think is what Alan means).

Answer (score 0):

copy your `.htaccess` file from your public folder and paste in your root directory
with this code inside `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```