# How to remove /public/index.php on a laravel url

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose that I have a wordpress installation on `www.wp-project.com` and I want  redirect to a laravel webpage in the same domain, for example `www.wp-project.com/laravel-project/login`.

Now I have a wordpress project (`wp-project`) inside `/var/www` and a laravel project (`laravel-project`) inside `/var/www/wp-project`.

When I want to access laravel webpage I need to use the following url

> www.wp-project.com/laravel-project/public/index.php/login.

I would like access as

> www.wp-project.com/laravel-project/login

Without `/public/index.php`.

How can I achieve that? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555171/how-to-remove-public-index-php-from-url-in-laravel-5) doesn't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: You can follow this
[deploy laravel](http://blog.netgloo.com/2016/01/29/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting/)

Comment: Your question shows that you do not understand HTTP server configuration. Learn about [Apache rewriting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) and [Nginx rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/). All you need to do is make some rewrite rules for the Laravel URL requests. This answer may help you: [Laravel project next to Wordpress project (in public_html folder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716585/laravel-project-next-to-wordpress-project-in-public-html-folder)

Answer (score 0):

**Go to mainlaravelproject/public>>**

a.  .htacess

b.  favicon.ico

c.  index.php

d.  robots.txt

e.  web.config

1.cut these 5 files from public folder,and then paste on the main project folder that’s means out side of public folder… mainlaravelproject/files

2.Next after paste ,open index.php ,modify

•require **DIR**.'/…/bootstrap/autoload.php';  to

•require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

```
modify

$app = require_once DIR.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; to

$app = require_once DIR.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: what if i dont want to change the laravel files structure?

Comment: @afikri that case you can also do that during hosting your website on live