# Apache rewrite url with Laravel 5 How to remove /public/index.php in the url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The apache root Document is ~/Sites/ .

My laravel project is called laravelTest in the ~/Sites/laravelTest

The index url is http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php

And restful url is http://localhost/laravel/public/index.php/$1/$2 ...

How can I remove the /public/index.php?

How do I setting the .htaccess file...

I only can remove the index.php ,but can't remove the /public/

Thanks.

Comment: [This one ?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28364496/3282633)

Comment: But it's not work for me...

Comment: The url http://localhost/laravelTest/public/ => can go my index page
now I want change to => http://localhost/laravelTest/
and I want restful url like http://localhost/laravel/$1/$2     Sorry I am apache noob lol

Comment: `localhost/laravelTest/public ` to  `localhost/laravel` So You want to change `laravelTest` to `larael` and then remove public too ?

Comment: I miss the Test  i just want remove the public. And I see the document, but don't know how to use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions for removing the `index.php` in Laravel 4,5 to remove `public/index.php` from URL

I would recommend you this simple step

1. Rename the file `server.php` in the your Laravel root folder to `index.php`
2. Move the `.htaccess` file from `/public` directory to your Laravel root folder.

Ref : [As simple like this](http://sysaxiom.com/remove-publicindex-php-from-your-laravel-project-in-two-steps/)

Comment: yeah , its work for me... But can't only use .htaccess file to control this?

Comment: We can do it but there are some severe cautions because of it. That's the reason i suggest this :)

Comment: And I also has question.  Now I can view my index in http://localhost/laravelTest/   but I thought http://localhost/laravelTest/public/  the resource(ex: img ) is 404  But i use laravel's Illuminate\Html provider for js ,css is work find. How can I use this for my img?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Have you found the way ? or shall i help you ?

Comment: No, I hav't foud the solution. Can yout help me?  Then I got another peoblem. lol  I do something in my controller then I want redirect to another website ,but the page nothing happend...  I use  return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');     Redirect::away('https://www.google.com');  Redirect::refresh('https://www.google.com');      Redirect::to('https://www.google.com');             but it doesn't work and no error.

Comment: this is my import. 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

Oh,I got error when I use Redirect::refresh
got error 
InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 470:
The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.

Comment: Can you give the full url like `return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');`

Comment: yeah ~ I'ved tried but it's the same.     The page not refresh and not redirect...