# remove public from url in laravel

Tags: .htaccess, http, laravel

I have seen many questions like [this](https://hellocoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel/), which solve in removing public in cases like `example.com/public`. But in my case i have `example.com/cases/public`. How to deal with this type of situatations.

Comment: Does your `DocumentRoot` (apache) or `root` (nginx) point to yourlaravelproject/public?

Comment: i don't know much about documentroot fir what i see here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#documentroot, my document root is /project/cases

Comment: It should point to `/project/cases/public`.

Comment: how to achieve that?

Comment: Are you working on a localhost or on a remote server? If on localhost are you using some package as XAMPP, EasyPHP, MAMP (depending on your OS)? If on a remote server - is it a shared hosting or a dedicated server (VPS)?

Comment: working on localhost using lamp

Comment: Then, follow this tutorial: It will help you setup a virtual host and configure it for Laravel or if you already have a VirtualHost for this project edit the configuration to fix your problem. http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps to remove the `public` from url

1. Copy **.htaccess** file from **/public** directory to *Laravel/project* root folder.
2. Rename the **server.php** in the *Laravel/project* root folder to index.php.

Cheers your will be good now.

Please Note: It is tested for **Laravel 4.2**, **Laravel 5.1**, **Laravel 5.2**, **Laravel 5.3**.

I think this is the easiest way remove `public`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove cases/public from url than you can use this

`RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cases/public http://example.com/ [R=301,L]`

Remove direction  R=301 in above line to make it internal redirection