# Add Public to asset path in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to install laravel in shared hosting and I followed the steps here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28449523 but my asset path doesn't include the public directory

Instead of this

```
<link href='http://example.com/public/assets/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I'm getting this

```
<link href='http://example.com/assets/css/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

How do I change the directory of the asset folder(add public to assets) without changing any core classes?

Comment: The tutorial you followed is for removing the Public segment. If you have really done it, you have removed, Public, haven't you? If your host has cpanel, all  you need is to click on Softaculous and installation is automatic, it will install it with the public segment in by default

Comment: but my asset path doesn't include the public folder
I want it to be included when using the asset() function.

Comment: It seems that you cannot achieve it without changing core classes.

Comment: try to change `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Before Laravel 5.7.14**

Take a look at `Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator` class and its `asset($path, $secure = null)` method. This class is being put to container by `url` key. What you can do is:

1. Add your own class, extending `UrlGenerator`;
2. Add `asset($path, $secure = null)` method to your own class, making it return whatever you need;
3. Create a service provider and register it in `config/app.php`;
4. In your service provider's `register()` method, bind your new class
   to the container by `url` key.

This way, you don't touch core files at all and your Laravel application is still update friendly.

**Update for Laravel 5.7.14 and later**

As other answers state, there is the `ASSET_URL` .env option, which makes it much easier to change the public path. Laravel introduced it in Laravel 5.7.14, which was released about 3 years after my original answer.

Comment: Sorry, What do you mean by binding the new class to the container by url key? how do I do that? And can I do that at the serviceProvider instead of creating a new one?

Comment: This can be done easily by defining ASSET_URL in .env

Comment: `ASSET_URL` was introduced in Laravel 5.7.14, released in late 2018. The question was asked and answered by me in 2015. I'm gonna update the answer, as many people just look at the selected answer.

Comment: @RoboRobok the ASSET_URL is not working if have admin panel URL for e.g www.example.com/admin

Answer (score 35):

Add **ASSET_URL=public** in your **.env** file and run **php artisan config:cache**

Comment: Works in laravel 5.8

Comment: running `php artisan config:cache` causes [issue](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/issues/323)

Comment: I am using Laravel 8. Thanks @Abid_015, It's work for me.

Comment: Not worked for me in Laravel 8

Comment: You can set ASSET_URL like yourdomain.com/public

Comment: I should set to ASSET_URL=/public so if my endpoint like this /admin/home, asset() path WILL NOT be yourdomain.com/admin/public - Laravel v10

Answer (score 19):

For the latest version of Laravel - Laravel 5.8, there is a key in **config/app.php** with name **asset_url**. The value of this key determines the value that the **asset()** method returns. Normally, you should set the value of this key to the base url of your website if all your asset folders are in the default location (this default location is the **public** folder under the root directory of your Laravel installation).

For example if your website url is "https://www.example.com" and you want to access the asset path **public/assets/css/sample.css** under the root folder, set the asset_url in config/app.php like this:

```
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', 'https://www.example.com'),
```

and use the asset function like this:

```
asset('assets/css/sample.css')
```

Thereafter, reconfigure your cache by running this within your laravel installation folder:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This will update the **bootstrap/cache/config.php** file. If you check your browser, the generated url for your asset would be "https://www.example.com/assets/css/sample.css".

One way you can have a valid url like: "https://www.example.com/public/assets/css/sample.css" is by creating another folder named **public** inside your already existing public folder - which is non-intuitive for me.
However, if you do this, then you have to include this path when using the asset function:

```
asset('public/assets/css/sample.css')
```

Comment: @miken32 is it a good practice to declare asset url in app.php?

Comment: @Umair yes, if you wish to use the `asset()` method in production.

Comment: @miken32 How do you use asset() method?

Answer (score 4):

A relatively easier hack is to add the folder in the return value of the asset() function inside \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php

```
public function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    if ($this->isValidUrl($path)) {


        return $path;
    }

    // Once we get the root URL, we will check to see if it contains an index.php
    // file in the paths. If it does, we will remove it since it is not needed
    // for asset paths, but only for routes to endpoints in the application.
    $root = $this->assetRoot
                ? $this->assetRoot
                : $this->formatRoot($this->formatScheme($secure));

    // Following 2 lines were added
    if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1')
        $root .= '/public';

    return $this->removeIndex($root).'/'.trim($path, '/');
}
```

Note here that I have added public to the return value based on a condition. So that can be done as well.