# Laravel 8 – use blade asset to display image, but loading from resources subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I’m quite new to Laravel, so patience with me.

I’m in the middle of the process of replicating a framework that I developed in node / react to laravel. Right now, I’m adjusting the main architecture and currently working on a blade master page.

**Goal 1:**

I want to load images using the blade {{ asset() }} helper in a template page. The thing is that I want to load the images from a subfolder that resides inside the resources folder:

```
/resources/app_files_layout
```

I know that I could do this by moving the folder to the public directory, but that’s not what I have in mind. My intention is also to advance on a deeper learning and understanding on the laravel framework and try to maintain an architectural fidelity with my framework on other languages.

**Goal 2:**

After I manage to load the images from the /resources/app_files_layout through {{ asset() }} helper in blade, I’d like to use an alias for the route in the source code. Example:
Instead of displaying in the output HTML in the browser http://localhost/app_files_layout/image-name.jpg, I’d like it to display: http://localhost/images/image-name.jpg and never show the user that the files are in a app_files_layout folder.

Is what I’m trying to do possible at all in laravel?

**Worst case scenario:**

If laravel doesn’t have the necessary architecture to do what I want, I could settle for setting up a route that displays the image in the /resources/app_files_layout folder. That is: when I access on the browser http://localhost/images/image-name.jpg should load an image located in /resources/app_files_layout/image-name.jpg.

I tried to follow this stackoverflow suggestion:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38736973/2510785
However, returned me an error like so:

```
The requested resource /files-layout-test/backend-layout-header-tb02-03.jpg was not found on this server.
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: If you want to dig in, here are the hints for you

1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810231/add-public-to-asset-path-in-laravel#answer-32839086 . Create new class and extend proposed one. Create new method called `assetImage` and specify your path. But try not to hardcode it inside of the method. Create some kind of `.env` variable for this and assign it also to config with default value.

2) How about `aliases` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399789/nginx-how-to-create-an-alias-url-route ?

3) Framework is not a thing inside of itself. Use tools which are at your disposal.

Comment: `/public` is the only path "publicly" available (via URL). Either create a link to your specific folder, create a webpack entry that copies your files to a folder inside the `/public` folder or link that folder (like it is done with the `/storage` folder when running `php artisan storage:link`.

Comment: Hi @SergeyLigus, I like the first approach. I´m going to try it, but as I said, I´m still a bit new to Laravel, so I may ask dumb questions. I found the file with the asset method in ```syncsystem-laravel8-v1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php```. So, my first question: do I create this new method in this same file? My concern is that if I do a ```composer install```, it would be erased. If not in this file, where would I created and how. Can you give a basic example?

Comment: @SergeyLigus, I also took a look at the second approach, but the intention would be to create a route alias in web.php file that could serve my asset files in resources subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do what I wanted for this one. All credit for [@donkarnash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220364/donkarnash) on this question that I posted for the worst case scenario for creating a route alias for it: [Laravel 8 – create route alias for image folder inside public directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340270/laravel-8-create-route-alias-for-image-folder-inside-public-directory)

I used the symbolic link approach, almost similar to what [@sergey-ligus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6136431/sergey-ligus) had mentioned in the comments.

1 – edit laravel \config\filesystems.php file:
Originally, looks like this:

```
links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

After I edited, looked like this:

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('files-layout') => resource_path('app_files_layout'),
],
```

2 - Then, in the command terminal, I executed the following command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

3 - Finally, I ran the server and tested out. Not only could I access the file in the browser via: http://localhost:8000/files-layout/backend-layout-header-tb02-03.jpg, but also could still use laravel asset blade helper.

Blade file:

```
{{ asset('/files-layout/backend-layout-header-tb02-03.jpg') }}
```