# Laravel 5.1 rewrite url not working

Tags: laravel

```
I am Working on Localhost (WAMP server, php version 5.5.12)
```

url: http://localhost/laravel/

my root directory .htaccess is:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Public Directory .htaccess is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
 </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In this scenario when I want to access: http://localhost/laravel/
following error message appears:
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

But when I access : http://localhost/laravel/public/
It successfully loads home page.  I have debugged every thing in url rewriting it works fine but laravel not accepting new urls. Can anyone please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: what type of web server are you using? wamp or php artisan serve or homestead?

Comment: I am using WAMP server

Comment: Why not use `php artisan serve`  it will save you the stress

Comment: move `index.php` and `.htaccess` file from `/public` folder to the root. you can get perfect answer from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url/32519877#32519877](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url/32519877#32519877)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this problem. From your public directory index.php file move in root directory like "project-name/index.php" 
Then edit your index.php file 
In line 22 replace 
"require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';" this with 
"require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';"

and line no 36 replace 
"$app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';" with 
"$app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';"

Now edit autoload.php from "project-name/bootstrap/autoload.php"
here replace line no 17 
"require **DIR**.'/vendor/autoload.php';" with
require **DIR**.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

now browse your project-name. I think it will solve your problem. You can also laravel development server as localhost:8000 for this open your project folder in command window and type "php artisan serve" hit Enter.

Comment: I have seen many posts which describe removing "public" from url using following htaccess:<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] </IfModule>   But I could not understanding How can that work in this scenario? Can you plz describe it?