# Laravel serving up pages from invalid route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

I have the following route: `Route::resource('users', 'ProfileController');`  When I go to `site.com/users/123`, it loads the page properly.  I can also go to `site.com/index.php/users/123` and get the same page (not sure if laravel is by default intended to do that).

If I change the url to `site.com/does_not_exist/users/123`, laravel returns a 404, as you would expect.  However, if I go to `site.com/does_not_exist/index.php/users/123`, laravel loads the page.  I can put any random path, non-existent path between site.com and index.php and it will work.

Why doesn't laravel return a 404 for this?  How do I fix it so it does?

Answer (score 0):

Because the index.php is the index.php in public folder that handles the incoming request and its a automatically generated class loader

This might work (similar question on how to fix this)

1-Renaming the server.php to index.php (no modifications)

2-Copy the .htaccess from public (like rimon.ekjon said below)

3-Changing .htaccess it a bit as follows for statics:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

If there are any other static files needed just add the extension to the previous declared list

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Comment: How would that help?  server.php is outside of the document root, no one is able to access it.