# Laravel application homepage is under Public directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have set up my first Larevel application on WampServer on my local machine under the directory 'laravel', When I type `localhost/laravel` it takes me to the file structure as shown below. I can only get to the homepage of the application when I type in `localhost/laravel/public`.

[image]

Here is my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

How do I configure my application to make the welcome page the root? Am I missing something here? Surely there is an easier way to do this than having to edit the .htaccess?

Comment: .htaccess is the way to go

Comment: Config you wamp to laravel/public directory.
My httpd-vhosts.conf:
`<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sockets.dev
  ServerAlias www.sockets.dev

  DocumentRoot E:/Projects/LaravelSockets/laravel/public/

  <Directory E:/Projects/LaravelSockets/laravel/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
  LogLevel warn
  ServerSignature Off


</VirtualHost>`

Comment: @mcklayin what if I'm not using vhosts? When I eventually move this app onto a production server I won't have access to the Apache configs so this is not a feasible option.

Comment: you want need to config it on a production server as thats done for you when setting up a domain name and that.  As this is a local version you will need to set up a vhost etc for the system to work.  You can try localhost/laravel/public and it should display but that will be it, it wont work form there etc without a vhost file etc as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ /laravel/public$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This worked, very quick and easy. I don't like the idea of setting up a vhost because when migrating to different environments it could be problematic. However with a .htaccess file it will pretty much work wherever I move my application to. Thanks!

Comment: Another option is to use https://laragon.org/ this modern LAMP Server automatically configures virtual host for your projects. If you create a project in the path www/laravel one virtualhost be created and you can access the url laravel.dev (this is configurable). Take the time to try this tool

Comment: This looks good but at this moment I am sort of forced to stay with the simplest solution without a vhost because when I host my application on a production server, it won't be configurable

Comment: But one question? I don't want my URL to have public in it, how do I change this?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28735930/5885326 it's amazing how easy it is!!!

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the apache config files you have a

```
<DocumentRoot "/path/to/laravel">
```

You should change this to

```
<DocumentRoot "/path/to/laravel/public">
```

For security reasons only a few files are 'put online', but public/index.php will still do everything you want.

After you have done this, make sure your .htaccess file is correct. If you don't your routes will not work properly.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

As shown here in the [laravel 5.1 doc's](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1). Not sure why they left it out in 5.2...