# How to remove public word from laravel URL (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: url-rewriting, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

Currently I am using Shared Web Hosting, and uploaded my Laravel project (`developed in Laravel 5.1`), but I have to type to public with domain name. 
eg: `abc.com/public/blogpage`

My Hosting seller not mapping my domain to `laravel public` folder so Its mapped to `public_html` folder.

Is there any way available to remove public word from URL? I tried to keep my files in `public_html` folder and moved `public` folder out of `public_html' folder, but no luck,

Kindly guideme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is recommended for those, who are using shared hosting and not able to remove public from route.

---

the easiest and simplest way to remove `public` keyword from Laravel routes is follow these steps.

1. Put all your files and folder except `Public` folder, outside
   `public_html` folder, I mean Root folder of your site.

   [image]
2. Then grab all files and folder from `Public` folder and put them
       into `public_html` folder.
   [image]

once done with this, then create a file (name it, paths.php) into your `bootstrap` folder (Laravel folder exists in your root folder) copy below code into `paths.php` file

```
<?php 

return array(

    'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
    'public' => __DIR__.'/../public_html',
    'base' => __DIR__.'/..',
    'storage' => __DIR__.'/../app/storage',
);
```

Now access your website without `public` word in URL, if you see error, then try to Hard reload (Ctrl + 5) it. Thats it

---

**Note**: This is not the recommended way, in shared hosting, better to ask your Hosting Manager/ re-seller to change your domain mapping on `public_html/public` instead `public_html`. and if you are using dedicated, cloud hosting then you can change it by yourself in your Virtual Host file.