# Font-face issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, font-face

After fixing '/public' URL using solution provided at link [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url) , there is new problem arise where the custom fonts in style.css stopped working.

Followed the solution provided by user @ka_lin , everything is working fine except the font-face.

Comment: Paths? Urls? Links? Some code?

Comment: There are many different approaches at the link from which you used the solution. Which one did you use? Defining a vhost is the most simple and most "Laravel like" solution. Many helper functions in Laravel depend upon the default paths assuming the default **public** folder - which should not be moved/altered. Provide some more info regarding your implementation.

Comment: Thanks piotr and Donkarnash but the approach which was using previously through link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url is not a standard one as it will expose important files like .env which usually present on root folder. So I used another approach and its working very well for me.