# Hosting Laravel 5.3 application on server

Tags: laravel-5.3, web-hosting

I build a Laravel 5.3 application on my local environment and now i want to deploy it on my hosted server.

On my server i already have a hosted Wordpress site. Actually i developed an application on Laravel and i want to host this on particular domain path.

for example suppose my Wordpress site is hosted on example.com

and i want to host my Laravel application on example.com/my-laravel-app

without affecting the Wordpress site

so how can i do this please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your public html directory a folder called "my-laravel-app" Wordpress will not try to serve it for you and it'll go directly to this folder.
You need to make sure that you point anyone who is visiting this directory to /public for laravel app to work (Or use any other question on SO like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url) for ignoring the /public path which is not recommended at all!).