# is laravel homestead websites are compatible with cpanel shared hosts?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, homestead

I'm new to laravel, and learning it with online tutorials, in many cases they use laravel homestead. I want to know if it is compatible with cpanel for deploying an app or it will cause a lot of trouble in deployment?

Comment: You can deploy a Laravel application to a cPanel server, yes. Some configuration will likely be required, and cPanel *sucks* and should never be used, but it's *doable*.

Comment: No problem at all. Maybe, later you need to remove public from your url. There is a solution for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url/46302555#46302555

Comment: thanks. my hosting provider doesn't have ssh access and I use htaccess rewrite. so other than this there will be no problem?

Comment: I wouldn't use a hosting provider that doesn't have SSH access. That's unacceptable in this day and age. Get a better host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in some Cpanel SSH Access is limited, this is a Huge problem in Laravel, no artisan, no composer.
The FTP Access allows you to Upload the files, but re-mapping of public url is not available using a Virtual Host, so you need extract the public folder.

Comment: thanks. my hosting provider doesn't have ssh access and I use htaccess rewrite. so other than this there will be no problem?

Comment: Make sure that the permissions of the storage folder are correct, but that I doubt that there are more complex problems. regards