# how to remove public from url in laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

I already remove the public from url when i access the website. i have just created **.htaccess** in root directory and that contains this code:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now when i access the website it is not showing public and running fine. Now problem is that when i type my website like :- www.example.com/public -> it is still opening i want to show 404 page can anyone help me how to do that.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Comment: rename server.php to index.php copy .htacess from public to outside

Comment: check this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Comment: @shashi this is bad idea because when you upload project in server then we can add public in every url

Comment: @kunal but the whole point is he want to remove public from url

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache server it can be done with the help of virtual hosts. In case IIS you can do it by setting your physical path directory to point to public directory of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow these steps to get it working:

```
 1. Rename server.php to index.php in the root folder of your project
 2. Now move the .htaccess file from public folder to the root folder of your project.
```

That's it. :)

Comment: but when i access the image in server then i need to add public there this is not good way