# Laravel on shared hosting resource error

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display images on laravel shared hosting but I cannot get it to work.

On my local host I am using this:

```
      return asset("assets/avatars/avatar.png");
```

But on my shared hosting it does not find the image. So I have to use this:

```
      return asset("public/assets/avatars/avatar.png");
```

With adding the public. Is there any way I can make it universal so I do not have to change the code everytime I upload?

Comment: Your `/public/` folder should be the domain root. You're leaking your `.env` file right now.

Comment: @Neat how am I leaking the .env file? :O

Answer (score 0):

Your Virtual Host should point to the `public/` folder. If cannot do that, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735930/2904719

Answer (score 0):

Cut all your files from `public` folder to `root`.

After cutting all of files `index.php` exists in `root`:

Replace `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php'` with `require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php'` in `index.php`.

Replace `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'` with `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php'` in `index.php`.

Comment: I have done that, otherwise I would not be able to run it on shared hosting. Only thing not working is my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply create a symlink to the `public` folder in your shared hosting. They normally provide cPanel or Plesk, which easily allows you to do that.