# remove Public Url . htaccess laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

remove public/ from url I search and try to follow these step

1. copy .htaccess from public/ and paste it into root /
2. change server.php to index.php
3. I try yo add

   RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

to my /.htaccess to remove url public It didnt work.

but if I remove that line It'work but all my Url link to css it's wrong path

```
NOTE :: I PUT all my Css into public/assets if I move folder assets  to my / It work but is their anyway If I dont want to move my floder assets
```

UPDATE .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you add a css link in html ?

Comment: sure  Its' remove my public and It go to http://localhost:8888/blog_kame/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I use {{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}

Comment: Try adding this `RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]` !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Comment: not working still go to same path

Comment: take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32580688/4881811) !!

Comment: I updated @Maraboc I do everything same as that ans why It still wrong path

Comment: sad why somthing weird  always happen to me LOL

Comment: You're trying to **add** `public` to the URL?

Comment: yes , I want to remove public all of path except folder assets which have css js img files

Comment: I think I do the right thing not sure why It's not working

Comment: Not sure, It about version or not In 5.4 I just add  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] well, every thing work find but in 5.5 I add these line laravel said not found page LOL

Comment: If I cant fix It, I think I'll move folder out of public but It look mess up

Comment: well   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] @Maraboc It's work If I use php artisan serve  but not working in my localhost

Comment: `public` should never be in the URL of any properly installed laravel application unless you're registered a route named public.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with 2 possible ways:

(1) Rename server.php in your Laravel root folder to index.php
    Copy the .htaccess file from /public directory to your Laravel root folder. For static files, you can change the htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

(2) No need to do anything with htaccess.

```
1) copy index.php in public folder. remove/rename index.php in public.

2) paste in root folder of the project

3) Now open index.php and change 2 url paths like below. 
   require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
   $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

That's all :)

In this way you need to change the js and css file paths by adding /public/ in those paths.