# Laravel File Manager dosn't load css, js files

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-filesystem

I integrated Laravel File Manager in my laravel project and at first it worked properly, but after I remove **public** [ I followed this instruction [remvove public from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url) ] from url it din't work anymore. The css file is missing and **browse file** also din't work. I tried to include those files**[css, js]** into **head** section also din't work. It still show like this

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this error. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you link to the package you are using?

Comment: Are  you using Unisharp LFM ?

Comment: Yes here is the link https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/

Comment: set your site root to project/public instead of  modifying htaccess

Comment: @MahdiYounesi How to do that? Could u tell me more?

Comment: in your Apache or Nginx or Xampp  configuration set DocumentRoot to projectDirectory/public  then if you visit  htttp://name.domain you  your project is up and  'public' is excluded form urls

Comment: This is not what I want. I want it to work on share hosting.