# Laravel 5.5 How to access website insted of /public folder

Tags: laravel

I have setup laravel 5.5 on my localhost and want to 
access the project directly instead of /public directory.
My Current link is: http://localhost/my_laravel/public/
I Want to access as: http://localhost/my_laravel/

Comment: What web-server are you using? Did you configure your server correctly according to [the installation guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/installation#web-server-configuration)?

Comment: I am using localhost with Xampp

Comment: You have to point your DocumentRoot to the public folder on your httpd.conf

Comment: Can you please help me with the step for localhost in xampp

Comment: google xampp laravel vhost setup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

start a server using

```
php artisan serve
```

in cmd/console go to the project directory and run the above cmd.

it will run your app on http://localhost:8000