# Waiting for localhost... never ends

Tags: laravel, tcp, localhost

I am using Laravel. In XAMPP's htdocs folder my laravel root folder name is sh.
I ran the following code

```
php artisan serve
```

and found that

```
 Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

In Browser Address Bar I wrote

```
localhost:8000
```

now

> waiting for localhost...

never ends.

I ran this code

```
C:\>netstat -a
```

in a long list I found that

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:8000         ommited-PC:0            LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:8000         ommited-PC:49674        ESTABLISHED
```

In Browser's address bar I wrote

```
http://localhost/sh/public/
```

the site opens correctly.

This is my observation. I don't know why localhost waits for ever and what should I do.

Answer (score 2):

### Solved

This was because of `Avast Antivirus`. By mistake Avast treated *`server.php`* file as a threat. I make an exception following this link

https://support.avast.com/en-ww/article/Antivirus-scan-exclusions

then the problem has been solved.

Comment: It exactly serves first request and then hangs on with "waiting....". Fixed by adding exception.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to run in different port. Check this thread for further detail... Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719658/run-laravel-project-in-localhost)