# How to clone and run vue laravel project with passport?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

currently i need to work on a project using laravel and vue

i cloned the project that i need to work on from github,

the project is using vue and laravel with passport

but i'm not sure what are the commands i need to use to run the project on my local machine

do i follow the same commands like when i clone a laravel project? or there is something extra for vue?

i tried to install passport and run few commands but still facing blank page

if someone can provide the commands in order that would be much appreciate it

Comment: Are you asking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48719658/437212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really difficult to say what commands needs to be run in your specific case, since we can't see the code. Also make sure your .env is set up correctly with database connections etc.

But generally you would need something like this.

1. Install packages

   **composer install**
   **npm install**
2. Create APP_KEY for Laravel

   **php artisan key:generate**
3. Run migrations to create all your database tables.

   **php artisan migrate**
4. Start artisan server for the Laravel backend. Default port is 8000, so you should reach it at http://localhost:8000

   **php artisan serve**
5. Compile the front end files

   **npm run dev**

But this is all guesswork. Your project could be set up different.