# Laravel 500 Internal Server Error Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am developing a website using Laravel and Ajax. I have a problem when I try to return all messages (Messages model) that belong to specific user (User model) using hasMany method.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/test', 'UserController@testFunction');
Route::post('/test', 'UserController@testFunction');
```

**UserController.php**

```
public function testFunction(Request $request) {
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $messages = User::find(1)->messages;
        return $messages;
    } else {
        return 'get method';
    }
}
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function messages() {
        $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'from');
    }
}
```

**Message model**

```
class Message extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'from', 'to', 'content'];
}
```

Then I have two buttons (just for testing - POST and GET). They are handled by this **JavaScript code**

```
window.onload = function() {
    // AJAX Setup
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    // Post Method
    $('#postMethod').click( function() {
        $.post('test', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    // Get Method
    $('#getMethod').click(function() {
        $.get('test', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
}
```

Tables in the databse have a structure as shown below:

- [users table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBIND.jpg)
- [messages table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvQy4.jpg)

When I click on POST button (handled by above javascript code), I receive this error in console: [error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnrw4.jpg)

If I change `$messages = User::find(1)->messages;` to `$messages = User::find(1)->name;`, for example, I get the name of the user with ID 1 returned to the console normally.

I assume that something is wrong with messages() function in UserController.php. Maybe 'from' as foreign key? This is just my guess, maybe the error is somewhere else, please take a look yourself.

Comment: I guess you have to pass the token too as parameter

Comment: Do you mean `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`? I have it in head tag of app.blade.php template.

Comment: Check the network tab to get more info or check laravel.log file to get more information about the error

Comment: no, not in the header but in the body like this, data: { _token: $('#signup-token').val()} ...

Comment: yes, and as @linktoahref said, check the logs for additional info

Comment: I checked Network tab now. This is what it says about the error: [link](http://shrani.si/f/1E/KH/2ZKmRXXs/error.jpg). Check the message.

Comment: You have a messages() method in the User model. Paste it here.

Comment: @Clain Blaga I already posted it in the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fix, you need to call messages like this `messages()` that will return relationship instance.

```
public function testFunction(Request $request) {
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    $messages = User::find(1)->messages();
    return $messages;
} else {
    return 'get method';
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This solves the error - it is no longer present. But the problem is that I am not getting any data back, even though it should return a message. This is my messages table data: [link](http://shrani.si/f/3t/Pb/2cXrIofy/table.jpg). As you can see, I have one message that belongs to user with ID of 1, but it isn't returned to the console. Is my `public function messages()` written correctly, especially the second parameter?

Comment: Try this `$messages = User::find(1)->messages()->get();`

Comment: If I add `get()` method, I get `POST 500 (Internal Server Error)` error again.

Comment: Ok, you can also do this in that way `User::where('id',1)->with('messages')->get();` , let me know If this works.

Comment: No, it gives `POST 500 (Internal Server Error)` error again. Is `with('messages')` part correct?

Comment: Can you show me what exactly error/exception you got ?

Comment: Console output: [link](http://shrani.si/f/R/vr/1XkwBUiU/console.jpg). Network tab output: [link](http://shrani.si/f/3Y/Ab/2ErIwtFw/network.jpg).

Comment: You are missing a return statement in your messages relation, it would be like this `return $this->hasMany('App\Message', 'from');`

Answer (score 0):

test with `/`.
Try this

```
// Post Method
    $('#postMethod').click( function() {
        $.post('/test', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });

    // Get Method
    $('#getMethod').click(function() {
        $.get('/test', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Comment: If I do this, I get error `404 (Not Found)` in console after clicking on the button.

Comment: @brainstorm your application is available `/` OR `/public`

Comment: @brainstorm Remove public from URL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url