# Laravel 5.5 routing

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, routes

i have a problem with routing on the site. Some days ago i am using .htaccess to rewrite "public/" directory to "/" using best answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url),
but then i try to use apache config to do this, and now none of route is working. Maybe someone can help me find mistake in configuration, or write default config(i try to find but get nothing to work), that i can set? So this is the conf that i use for my site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zexchange.tmweb.ru
    ServerAlias www.zexchange.tmweb.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www-root/data/www/zexchange.tmweb.ru/public
    ServerAdmin webmaster@zexchange.tmweb.ru
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    AddDefaultCharset off
    AssignUserID www-root www-root
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/zexchange.tmweb.ru.access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/zexchange.tmweb.ru.error.log
    <FilesMatch "\.ph(p[3-5]?|tml)$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@zexchange.tmweb.ru"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/www-root/data:."
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f webmaster@zexchange.tmweb.ru"
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/www-root/data/mod-tmp"
        php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/www-root/data:."
    </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/www-root/data/www/zexchange.tmweb.ru/public>
    Options +Includes -ExecCGI
    <IfModule php5_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule php7_module>
        php_admin_flag engine on
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

use the default laravel .htaccess and in your apache config point to the public folder.

So just add in your apache config

```
DocumentRoot to /var/www/yourlaravelapp/public
```