# How to remove 'public' from Laravel URL (v5.6) when Laravel is installed in a subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm using WordPress for my business site and Laravel for Project management application.

Here is my directory structure.

```
public_html
    -mainsite (my WordPress site is in this directory)
    -work (Laravel Application is in this directory)
```

When user visits my primary domain (e.g. www.example.com) I'm redirecting the visitor to www.example.com/mainsite using following .htaccess rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainsite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mainsite/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ mainsite/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

My project management application which is located in 'work' directory is easily accessible with this URL

```
www.example.com/work/public
```

Now I want to allow users to access my project management application with this URL
(I want to remove 'public' from URL)-

```
www.example.com/work
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

(It is easy to remove 'public' from URL when Laravel is installed in the root directory and I know how to do that)

**This is not a duplicate question and here is the reason-
My Laravel installation is in subdirectory of my root directory and I'm also using different site (a WordPress site) for my base URL**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate question. My Laravel installation is in subdirectory of my root directory and I'm also using different site (a WordPress site) for my base URL

Comment: Are u using Vhost ?

Comment: I'm on Linux shared hosting plan by Bigrock.

Comment: In shared hosting you need to bring all files in public folder outside it and edit index.php

Comment: As I explained I've a WordPress installation in another folder, which loads on my base URL, so there is no chance to move Laravel files outside public folder. I want to load both installations (WordPress and Laravel)

Comment: i mean put it in the root folder of ur project not complete outside to the root of ur public_html

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: you are using your laravel as addon domain right?

Answer (score 0):

- Move Laravel to outside of public_html
- Move content of Laravel's public folder to public_html/work
- Put the following code in the \App\Providers\AppServiceProvider register():

  $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path('public_html/work');
  });