# public/index.php to remove / redirect to domain in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have developed one laravel application. Initially we have executing `http://127.0.0.1/laravel_app/public` this url structure.

Ater completing application i have moved to server with domain.

Example: `http://www.example.com` it working fine. I have integrated `.htaccess` to remove public. its working fine.

But i have try to `http://www.example.com/public/index.php` 
above url manually typed site will display.

How can remove if users enter manually enter this type of URL `http://www.example.com/public/index.php`

Comment: have you put file `index.php` outside of public folder..?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're asking how to redirect users that hit a `http://yoururl/public/what/ever/after` to the same without the `/public`?

Comment: I think this will work, add this to your `.htaccess` file `
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

Comment: Why don't you just disallow access to the `public` folder from the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url this

Comment: You can select the root folder for your domain in the domain editor of your webspace. There you just tell the domain that it's root folder is `/laravel_app/public` and every request to your domain is going to be forwoarded to this folder. You can also do this on your local maschine, either laravel homestead or xampp or whatever you link.

Comment: Laravel's `public` folder should be your domain's root. This involves some webserver configuration, but is important for making sure the non-public files are inaccessible to browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code in your .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You should not. Putting your non-public files in a web-accessible spot is not a good idea - it is a potential security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```