# How to remove public from url in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 in my shared hosting server. I would like to remove public from url without changing server.php to index.php in root directory as doing so .env and other files are publicly visible. My .htaccess look likes below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,NC]

# Handle Front Controller...

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|media)/(.*)$ /public/$1/$2 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Why you are not pointing you domain to public directory?

Comment: How do I do that and is it the only option ? @KamalPaliwal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to point you domain to public folder from cpanel.

or

Move your .htaccess file from the /public directory to the root directory and replace it content with the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create new 
.htaccess file in root directory 
and paste with the following code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56___lsphp .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 1):

The Best Solution for this will be pointing your apache document root to laravel's public folder.
But as you said you are using shared hosting then that **might** not be possible for you.

Now to access laravel app without public in the url follow this question
[Laravel 5 - Remove public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Also, you are concerned about other folders like app, config etc to not be accessible from the browser. Therefore to do that you can place an `.htaccess` 
file with contents `Deny from all` in every folder that you want to block access from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact working solution i found. Solution is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url/54275198#54275198), answered by Pallav Nagar

Create .htaccess file in root directory and place code something like below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not different from the checked correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In root folder make .htaccess file with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```