# Delete /public and Use / directly - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use a **path / directly** in the Laravel project, but without changing the path, I want to leave the project as it is, not to change the location of public files, and I tried to do this via `.htaccess`, but did not work in **localhost** :(

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But nothing changed, it did not work ... and the default path remained **/public**

Comment: Try this @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Comment: Ahhh!! It's work !!

Comment: Glad to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: Try to add public in APP_URL IN env file or app/config.php file

Comment: Ahh!! I found a mistake!

Comment: Any other way to do that without edit server.php file ?

Comment: add public/ in your assets file route

Comment: I mean! other way and with .htaccess for example ?

Comment: Have you try to put public in APP_URL in env file?  Then you have to clear cache by php artisan config:cache try this.

Comment: Not work! :( Thanks @Niral Patel - how can I change this path? any way without showing or using /public

Comment: Because I found a script at Codecanyon use / but without edit server.php - just with .htaccess - but for me not work :(

Comment: Hi, Can you edit your Answer with: this https://gist.github.com/liaotzukai/8e61a3f6dd82c267e05270b505eb6d5a it's work for me :) - to make my question as solved!