# .htaccess rule for SSL and public folder redirecting

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I want to edit my .htaccess file so all the requests will be encrypted (I have SSL certificate active). I'm trying to run a Laravel app, which has Index file in public folder and I want to let user access my page without the /public/ part in URL.

So far, I managed to do this:

This part let me access the page without the /public/ part.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

This part redirects all data to HTTPS:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.club/public_html/1 [R,L]
```

The question is, how do I merge these two together? They work separately, but not if I put this together in .htaccess file.

.htaccess file is located in `public_html` which is located in root folder. Laravel folders (incluing `public`) are located in this folder.

Comment: The answer to this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48494280/4233553 Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: unfortunately not. I found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48494280/4233553