# Correct Vue after removing the public from the path

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-5.7

I removed the "public" from the path use this instruction [Laravel 5 – Remove Public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

But now vue scripts do not work. 
If you add to the path public script works (http://example.com/public/anket)

Comment: Why would you want to remove public/ from public files url though?

Comment: To ensure that users do not type "public" after the site address

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you were trying to remove /public from public directory (.js or .css files)

Answer (score 0):

After modify you need changing .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

This way static files will not be ignored and Vue components will work again.

Regards