# How to remove only public from url not index.php

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, url

In my url `http://example.com/public/index.php` in my laravel website.
i want to remove only public remember not index.php
i want to see my url like `http://example.com/index.php`

public .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 – Remove Public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

Comment: no. there remove both public/index.php. but i want to remove only public not  index.php. remember not index.php

Comment: When I made one of my demo projects live, I just pointed my subdomain till the public folder path. So, now `public` isn't present in the URL and everything runs perfectly. Don't see why people deal so much with .htaccess here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rewritebase, if you want to only remove public and not index

```
# invoke rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~app-folder-name/

# add trailing slash if missing
    rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

if You want to remove public/index, set document root in your apache2 config.

Comment: RewriteBase /~app-folder-name/  which folder name add?

Comment: @MizanurRahman your project folder public directory maybe something like `myapp/public/` if your htaccess is outside your project folder, if  your htaccess file is inside your project folder, it will be only `public/` I guess.

Comment: RewriteBase public/   like that?

Comment: @MizanurRahman just replace the text `app-folder-name` with your folder name.

Comment: Please see my question details and please try understand. i could remove public/index.php but not remove only public.

Comment: @MizanurRahman Can you please tell me where your htaccess file is placed?

Comment: this .htacces is in root directory

Comment: @MizanurRahman You can try `RewriteBase public/` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `.htaccess` file from `public` folder to the root folder and replace the code with the below code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

try the code and let me know.