# Laravel webpage not work without /public suffix

Tags: html, laravel, hosting

My mate has a website which is hosted. The website uses Laravel. Suddenly images and style-sheets have stopped working. I recognized when i enter the site with / public suffix everything seems to work. Could you tell me how can i deal with it? I am almost sure that this is a question of one change in some config file but cant't find answer on the internet.

Comment: What's your virtual host configuration?

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Comment: Try loading the website and inspecting the source code. Click on the links to the style sheets and see if they load. What are you using to run the default /public folder when you load the website? .htaccess file maybe?

Comment: @MatHatrik Thank you for your attention. I have changed .htaccess file.