# Laravel 5 & Vue components – Remove Public from URL

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 project with Vue components. The project works fine.

But I removed the "/public" from the path using this instruction: [Remove /public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)

And now vue components don't work. Which files do I need to modify to recover Vue components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself.

I hope this doesnt affect my status. Please administrators let me know...

After modify I need changing .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

In this way the static files components will not be ignored. Like this components work again

Answer (score 0):

Let me share my experience.
Inside public folder, there is .htaccess file.
You can copy it into project directory.
And in vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Helpers.php, change asset file like this.

```
 function asset($path, $secure = null)
 {
     return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
 }
```

It is some bad of touching src file, but it is working well always.
Hope it would help you.

Comment: May be works. I didnt try. I have always believed taht you shouldnt touch any that is in /vendor. Everithing found in /vendor directory must be handled only by composer.