# Laravel 8.4 – Remove Public from URL

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-8

I am working on creating a website that converts text into speech. I am using the script from codecanyon which is Developed with PHP 7.4.x and Laravel 8.4.x . The issue I am facing is that I don't want to show **/public** URL as a permalink to access the website. Now, if I type mywebsite.com/pubic then the website is accessible otherwise if I write mywebsite.com then it only shows the files. I followed some of the previous queries posted on StackOverflow but got no results.
The topic I followed is [Laravel 5 – Remove Public from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url)
I tried even by renaming server.php , copying .htaccess and rewriting it. But those all resulted in a screen showing up errors or even blank.

My .htaccess file is;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Either use `php artisan serve` or point your server's "DocumentRoot" to the public folder

Comment: @brombeer Second option worked best. How can I change the DocumentRoot for the folder inside the subdmain to /public . I mean changing from myweb.com/tool to myweb.com/tool/public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the **/public** from the URL you are not going to use the .htaccess file.

What you are going to do instead is set the **/public** folder as the serving directory for your Server.

If you use Apache, just go to your **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** file and change the DocumentRoot from **{your base folder}/** (usually /var/www) to **{your base folder}/public**

Comment: That's a nice suggestion and it worked. But now I want to redirect mywebsite.com/tool    to    my website.com/tool/public. I mean I want to change the root of mywebsite.com/tool . any suggestion via cPanel

Comment: @ArbabAli if the answer worked may you mark it as the solution so that can help other people?
Regarding your next question, you usually do not want to use subfolder to serve different applications as webservers cannot handle subfolders but only domains and subdomains.

For this reason is strongly suggested to use a subdomain instead, something like tools.mywebsite.com, and through a virtualhost send the traffic to the tool/public folder

Comment: Why not. For now, I am looking for some other suggestions too. Regarding the query, I already created a subdomain and working on it. If you have checked the link, it is tools.impressim.com. Regarding the query, I asked above of changing the document path for mywebsite.com/tool to my website.com/tool/public. I contacted the hosting provider they did some changes in the .htaccess but still, it is not working as desired. While changing the path at  subdomain level works ok. Any help, how can I do it? so that myweb.com/tool has document path to myweb.com/tool/public.

Answer (score 1):

The content of public folder should go to the public folder of your server (fe it's public_html on my server), and everything else should be stored in a different folder (fe laravel_mywebsite). Then you should go to public_html/index.php and change the folder paths based on where you put your Laravel app.

Comment: do i have to change the server.php file name to index.php?

Comment: perfect answer. I used this and it's working perfectly

Comment: Hello, please note that if you adopt this solution you are exposing your environmental variables to the internet, that's why Laravel adopt a public folder. If you navigate to your website/.env file you'll notice

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use .htacces, you just need to rewrite all requests from /public to /

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R=301]
```