# How to rewrite shared hosting root to the public folder and redirect /public back to the root?

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, public

I have a Laravel project which was moved from custom VPS into shared hosting.

Rewrite all from root to the public was easy part.

But when i go to the domain.com/public page works...

So how i rewrite domain root to the public, but redirect direct acces to the domain.com/public back to the domain.com/ ?

Disclaimer:
There is plenty threads about Laravel and rewrite to the public folder. But no one works as expected.

Comment: Be aware of that kind of configuration: when everything is set and working as you'd think, check if `https://www.example.com/.env` is accessible from client/browser. Where example.com is your arbitrary domain.

Comment: If you [edit] so that this is a question you can post your answer to that question. Posting what appears to be an answer as a question will confuse some people.

Comment: @Tpojka i tried rename index.php in public to _index.php to try the configuration. Files in root are not accessible because all is forced to the public. But i got your tip. When i access domain root i got forbidden response. When i try access something in root i got 404 (because is not in public folder..) So i think this works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Because most shared hosts do not let you change the directory of the main domain, this is a common problem. With Laravel, you must point the domain to the public folder.

While it is possible, be aware that with this solution you would be playing whack-a-mole with security issues were the app to ever update, as noted by @Tpojka you might be at risk of leaking secrets such as from your .env file.

A better solution which was described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115900/hostinger-laravel-shared-hosting/71116219#71116219) is to move the Laravel app directory somewhere else and either copy or symlink the public/ folder contents. This way the app's actual files are not publicly accessible. You will need to make sure if you need to symlink storage/ that you move it to the proper document root as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution so i want to share it with others.

This have to be in the root directory.
Public directory .htaccess file have to be emtpy.

Like others comments here. After setup this you need check if your sensitive files like .env is not visible.

try domain.com/.env and if you dont get .env file you are good.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# That was ONLY to protect you from 500 errors
# if your server did not have mod_rewrite enabled


    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Prevent direct access to the "public" folder - redirect to root
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /public/
    RewriteRule ^public/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]

    #RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [R=302,L]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    # - but look for the file in the "public" folder
    #   (ensure we are not already in the "public" folder)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

    # Rewrite "everything" to the "public" subdirectory if not already
    # This ignores existing files/dirs in the document root
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)
    RewriteRule !^public/ public/%1 

    # Handle Front Controller... (as before)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

Comment: This code works, but you have to make a copy of server.php and rename it to index.php. Worked for me.