# Use a Laravel Application alongside another scripts (wp/joomla/...) and remove /public

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my directory structure:

```
Public_html
  /app
  /bootstrap
  /config
  /database
  /public
  /resources
  /routes
  /vendor
  /storage
  /another-sctipt
```

I'm trying to use Laravel application alongside `/another-sctipt` (wordpress in my case) and remove `/public` from Laravel URLs.

The problem is when I use a simple `.htaccess` file to remove `public`, it shows 404 for `/another-sctipt` directory.

Now the only way I can do is https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735930/6934036.
But it's not a secure way because it exposes `.env` file (mentioned in comments).
Is this really unsecure way even if I change my `.env` file permission to `600`?

And is there a better way to achieve this?

*notes:

I can't change webserver configs.*

Comment: How do you differentiate between your Laravel and WordPress CMS URLs? "not a secure way because it exposes `.env` file" - it's easy enough to secure any file from direct access.

Comment: @MrWhite any URL that  starts with the directory name (`another-sctipt` in my example) have to handle by WordPress, otherwise it have to handle by Laravel.
If I use this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/28735930/6934036 with correct file permissions, it doesn't make a security issue, right?

Answer (score 0):

Now I'm using this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  !^/another-sctipt/.*$
RewriteRule ^another-sctipt/(.*)$ another-sctipt/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/ [L,QSA]
```

it works