# Remove public/index.php from url

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5. I would like to change the route from

```
localhost/projectname/public/index.php/someroute
```

to

```
localhost/projectname/someroute
```

`mod_rewrite` is already enabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, change your webroot to be `/public`, then ensure that the `.htaccess` file in the public folder is the correct one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I can remove "public/index.php" in the url generated laravel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-i-can-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)