# Laravel with simple routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello I'm new here and I've been trying to learn Laravel but have fallenat the first hurdle.  I have searched for the answer and tried several suggestions but nothing worked for me.  I am running Wamp and have installed Laravel with composer.  I have my routes.php file

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@home');


Route::get('about', 'pagesController@about');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

The welcome controller works fine it's the other two I just get a 404 not found error.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is that 404 error from apache or Laravel?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, I'm not sure it says it in the browser when try to load the page.

Comment: Sorry I'm a newbe but your help is appreciated

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /about was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at test Port 80

Comment: post your htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

That's 404 error that you get is from apache. You need to call your page with `http://site/index.php/home`. If you want remove index.php from the url then you have to to re-write the url [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-i-can-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel).

Comment: ok thanks I've tried adding to the .htaccess file (in the public folder do I need one in the project root folder) but that didn't work.  I changed the server.php to index.php to get rid of the /public/ directory in the url.  was that the wrong thing to do?  Should I attempt method two and move all the content into root?

Comment: If you using wamp try to access public folder like http://site/public/index.php/home. if you add .htaccess to remove index.php from url then try to access like http://site/public/home

Answer (score 0):

If you using wamp try to access public folder like `http://site/public/index.php/home`. 
If you add .htaccess to remove index.php from url then try to access like `http://site/public/home`

> Apache
>
> The framework ships with a public/.htaccess file that is used to allow
>   URLs without index.php. If you use Apache to serve your Laravel
>   application, be sure to enable the `mod_rewrite` module.
>
> If the .htaccess file that ships with Laravel does not work with your
>   Apache installation, try this one:
>
> ```
> Options +FollowSymLinks
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
> ```

as laravel documentation says. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0#server-requirements

Comment: Ok thanks,  I've just realised that I can run php artisan serve in the command line, I had to change the server.php back.  Is it better to develop it that way?  Thanks for advice.

Comment: php artisan serve will run Laravel's Built-in Web Server. You can also set up another web server.