# No root access for uploading Laravel Project

Tags: laravel-5, web-hosting

My hosting provider doesn't allow me to upload files on root. It only give access to public folder.
I tried to move **index.php** & **.htaccess** files from Project's public directory to Server's Public Directory. It temporarily solve the problem. But I have to change every single file structure. Otherwise it doesn't find link. So please suggest me to upload my Laravel Project on such Host.

Comment: You'll have to add a .htaccess file in your public folder with proper rewrite rules. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain-name.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain-name.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

Of course, replace domain-name.com with your actual domain.

What this does is, it internally forwards all requests to your public folder. For example `www.domain-name.com/lorem-ipsum` will be redirected to `www.domain-name.com/public/lorem-ipsum`.

However, I have not tested this but it should work well in theory.