# laravel 5 deployment to ftp /liveserver

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, ftp, live

I just finished my first laravel application. Before get the hosting, I already sent an email to support and they said that they don't see any reason not to work. I also have already bought hosting and domain I have few questions now.

Is there anything that I supposed to do in the code in order to make it work? If so, what?

also I have copied everything in `/web/` that I have in my app.

```
extra folder
laravel folder(main juicy folder)
vendor folder
composer.json 
composer.lock
```

Is there anything else that I should do? the application does not seem to work when I try to access the main website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you place the files so that Laravel public folder matches your hosting public folder (probably named public_html).

I recommend reading this Laracast [discussion](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5).

Comment: Note that some hosting providers won't let you do this because of security reasons. In this case, see the accepted answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel

Comment: The whole solution touches Laravel files, you won't change the directory structure on host

Comment: Yes that's why I said "Note that". Just saying in case he isn't able to do it your way. But, I agree that changing the public directory is the best way. So see my comment as a workaround.