# Move Laravel 5 application in server subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel

So, I've developed a fully functional Laravel 5 application and deployed it onto my customer's server, running Apache2, PHP5 and MySQL. The app works as expected and URLs are correctly rewritten.
I now need to simply clone my app to another server, which runs exactly the same stack. Problem is I need to put my app in a subfolder, so that it can be accessed via URLs matching the pattern `domain2.com/movedApp`.

In other words:
First server responds to:

```
domain1.com/my/routes
```

Second server needs to respond to:

```
domain2/movedApp/my/routes
```

I tried to reproduce exactly the VirtualHost directive which works on the first server, adding `/movedApp` where needed and adding `RewriteBase` to the `.htaccess` file in the new `public` folder, but to no avail.

I've noticed that routes are correctly followed from URLs like:

```
domain2.com/movedApp/public/index.php/my/routes
```

Still I get 404 error on assets in Apache2 log.

I hereby report my `.htaccess` file located in the `public` folder of my working Laravel application.

> .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I also report the configuration file used by the web server to serve my app

> default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/galmaster/public
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/galmaster/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: have you get any success?

Comment: Yes, I actually have. I shall post the details as soon as I have some spare time. I managed to address the problem with just two `.htaccess` files.

Comment: I posted an answer to my own question for you to check out. Maybe my solution also works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've been fiddling a lot with VirtualHost(s), but the best solution I found does not involve them at all, and here it is.

First thing to do is to configure `.htaccess` files for both the **app's root folder** and its **public** folder.
I found a simple working `.htaccess` file in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel), which I report here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The default `.htaccess` works fine, instead, for the `public` folder.

The last step is to correctly configure your routes in `routes.php`. The workaround which works for me is quite rough, and maybe one could find some more refined solution, but still here it is.

```
// Get base (root) route
$base_route = basename(base_path());

Route::get($base_route, function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get($base_route.'/myRoute', function() {
    return view('myRoute');
});
```

So basically you need to prepend `$base_route` to every route in your app. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying your solution, but implicates in changing Laravel authentication, wich is painfull.

Comment: I actually don't remember having to fiddle with authentication. What issues are you encountering?

Comment: Redirects before and after login (to generate oauth2 token, for example) send to the wrong path, because I cannot edit auth middleware.

Comment: True indeed! Guess in this case you will need to properly configure your VirtualHosts.