# How to remove public in url (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

Hi need some help please, I want to remove the public in the url example `http://localhost/mysite/public/dashboard` intto `http://localhost/mysite/dashboard` . My attempt is putting the .htaccess from public to  the root of mysite..but when I access my site the css, js,images are not found. can someone help me on this please. I don't want to set up virtual host because I could not access my site in my tablet or mobile phone.

here is the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to configure your server to use `public` as the server document root.

Comment: There is a good answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel here.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

put an .htaccess file at root of your application and write this, it will work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```