# Laravel routing page not fount error while passing veriable

Tags: laravel

I am new to the Laravel while I reading the documentation I had a problem under routing.. it shows we can pass verifiable like this,

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

here what is the `user` is it `Controller` or `veritable` name. I tried to pass the verbal like below but it is getting error

[image]

my route code is ,

```
Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
    echo 'ID: '.$id;
});
```

Comment: can you show complete route.php.because its working form me.and also make sure laravel project folder name spelled  is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route is correct

```
Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
    echo 'ID: '.$id;
});
```

i have tested it and its working fine

Can you check .htaccess file under public folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Also make sure about laravel project folder name is spelled correctly

Comment: .htaccess  , I was tiring to remove public from URL I did some changes on htaccess . thanks

Comment: okay.you can point your domain to public folder .if you are using it in local you can check few stackoverflow answers

Comment: if you have any link.. pls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel

Comment: is that possible for L5.3 ? because i tried 2nd one but i couldn't find such files in my Latavel source folder..

Comment: i am not sure about laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the url field you trying to get to `public/32` and you should try to request such a url:

```
http://localhost/blog-laravel/public/user/32
```

Comment: can use Route::get('/{id}

Comment: @filip.your answer is coreect for first route but op is mentioning about another route my route code is ,

Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
    echo 'ID: '.$id;
});

Comment: `
Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
    echo 'ID: '.$id;
});`

Comment: I didn't saw that. Probably this should works. Could you show your *.htaccess* file?