# defining url for access within Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a directory of Laravel projects on a NGNIX server. I would like to access each project with this kind of format

```
http://<domain>/<project_name>
```

I would like for Laravel to recognize this as well - but -  the only to access the project (as of now) is by writing

```
http://<domain>/<project_name>/public
```

My problem is similar to this one - but not quite so:
[How can I remove "public/index.php" in the url generated laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)

In the Server Configuration file for the domain (under NGNIX), I have the following defined:

```
server {
[... snip ...]
root /var/www/cons.cclv.nancys.club/;
[... snip ...]
}
```

Can I perhaps use something like

```
server {
[... snip ...]
root /var/www/cons.cclv.nancys.club/*/public;
[... snip ...]
}
```

to resolve the issue?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with Laravel Homestead.
Here is the [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)