# Laravel route not working and showing local folders

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello i am having this strange issue with laravel 5.4 is once i started i added new route **admin** to load dashboad view but it didn't work and instead it listed local folders inside **public/admin** even when i made the route return string instead of using the **AdminController** same result happened

**Controller**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
   public function dashboard()
   {
       return view('admin.dashboard');
   }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

/*
 * Admin Routes
 */
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@dashboard');
```

**URL** http://website.dev/admin/

**The result on web
page**

[image]

Comment: Show the route definition

Comment: What is route definition sorry i am still new to laravel

Comment: do you put your view files in `public/admin` ? it should be under `resources/view` instead

Comment: This seems like apache's directory listing extension result. If you using apache then you must set .htaccess correctly.

Comment: My views are under D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\pharmacy\resources\views\admin\daskboard.blade.php  but even i am not reaching the point where i load the view

@kodmanyagha yes i am actually using apache via XAMPP but how can i fix this problem thought .htaccess ?

Comment: @YasserMoussa this is what your looking for - [disable directory listing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing) also make sure mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: @Gal i did that solution by hashing line 260 in httpd.conf like that #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI  but nothing changed :(

Comment: @YasserMoussa when you try other route names they are working fine ?

Comment: yes exactly!! when i tried new route for example adminnn it worked .. but with this particular word "admin" it didn't work i think i am missing something :-/

Comment: @YasserMoussa well its because you have a directory that being called 'admin'.laravel provided .htaccess file checks for folder & file existence before rewriting the url.this is how it should be,change the folder name or the route name to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a `.htaccess` Problem, did you setup the `.htaccess` for the Root Directory?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The `.htaccess` must be in the Root Directory of your Project.

Another simple Approach is to rename the `server.php` inside the Root Directory to `index.php`.

You may also take a look at [this Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel).

Comment: I added .htaccess file and renamed server.php to index.php and nothing changed

Comment: No this is my problem when i run this link i see folders from inside D:\xampp\htdocs\projects\pharmacy\public\admin .. when i should see dashbload.blade.php view is loaded :(

Comment: This must be a Problem with your .htaccess File. What if you add "Options -Indexes" to your .htaccess? And what if you go to http://website.dev/public/index.php/admin ?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure there will be a `directory` named `admin` inside your `public` folder to solve this problem you have to change your `directory` name to another name because when you hit URL `host_name/admin` its goes directly inside your admin
 folder instead of loading your `public/index.php`