# .htaccess to point to correct Laravel installation

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5.4

In my document root, I have deployed two Laravel applications to two different subfolders. (i.e. http://example.com/dev and http://example.com/test). Here **dev** and **test** are the subfolders.

I want http://example.com/demo/task/132 to be directed to http://example.com/demo/public/task/132.

```
\[document root]
-- \dev
   -- [laravel home]
-- \test
   -- [laravel home]
```

Is there a way to handle *public* folder in the paths using .htaccess? Basically I want to get rid of *public* from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this :

dev/public/.htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /dev/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

test/public/.htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /test/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you mean to put it inside `dev/.htaccess` instead of `dev/public/.htaccess` ?

Comment: It doesn't work no matter if I put it either to `dev/.htaccess` or `dev/public/.htaccess`. I get an error raised from RouteCollection.php

Comment: Is your mod_rewrite module enabled in php?

Comment: Also in your virtualhost check is allowoverride is set to All instead of None

Comment: This is a shared hosting environment and I was able to run the application when I had installed it to root folder. Then my .htaccess was pointing to public folder and it was working perfectly. That is, I was able to go to example.com/task/312. Therefore, I think mod_rewrite should have been enabled.

Comment: Check this out if it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel