# remove index.php from laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, routes

I've a laravel 5.4 over apache centos server.

the folder structure are like:
/var/www/html <- public folder
/var/www/project <- laravel project folder
/var/www/html contains the "public's laravel folder" content like css/ js/ and index.php etc.

index.php contains references to the project main folder.
the project works but just with ip like:

```
myip/index.php/login
```

and not

```
myip/login
```

as I would like
I try many way to remove it but without luck, this is my .htaccess file inside /var/www/html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]


# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove "public/index.php" in the url generated laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)

Comment: i found this post before but didnt work for me...and do not need even to cut the "public" part

Comment: How is `DocumentRoot` is set in the apache configuration?

Comment: is set to /var/www/html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the `.htaccess` file, you should change the server configuration to serve files from Laravel public folder.

Before editing the config file and to be safe, copy the default config file to have a backup: `cp /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.original`

Edit the file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` as the follwoing:

change this line:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/project/public"
```

Add the follwing lines to allow serving files from Laravel public folder:

```
<Directory "/var/www/project/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Run `sudo apachectl configtest` to make sure you did not make any mistake. You should get `Syntax OK`.

Restart the apache server to apply the new configuration. `sudo systemctl restart httpd`

Finally, restore the `.htaccess` file to the default version that comes with laravel at this [link](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/098b8a48830c0e4e6ba6540979bf2459c8a6a49e/public/.htaccess).

It's better to create a virtual host instead of changing the default configuration. However, this will be ok if you have only on website on the server.

Comment: looks so strange what happen right now, keep in mind that storage got "775" permission yet: https://ibb.co/frCXnb looks to the login part visible!

Comment: try `chmod -R 775 storage`

Comment: and I have no idea how is the login form coming out this way. so strange !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to go on the laravel documentation deployement/apache and you will see the rewriter rules you need to put them rules in your apache configuration. And all will work

Answer (score 0):

For those who work with laravel 7.x: MAke sure have .htaccess in both public and root folder of your project with bellow content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

By the way, don't forget to set AllowOverride to All in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (on CentOS):

```
<Directory "/var/www/path/to/my/app/public">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Goodluck.

Comment: Hello you need to go on laravel documentation for deployment and Apache section you will see the rewriter because apache does not support rewrite rules