# Laravel 5.8 Remove index.php from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5.8

I did try lots of solution from different resources like GitHub, StackOverflow, etc, but didn't get the solution to remove index.php from url in laravel 5.8 version. This issue occurs only in version 5.8

Here is my .htacess file code. Which is placed on root directory:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel/portal/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

If somebody has a solution. Please let me know

Comment: The Laravel documentation has a section [Web Server Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8#web-server-configuration). Have you tried that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I Remove “public/index.php” in the URL Generated Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)

Comment: @emix please check version of laravel which i mentioned

Comment: It doesn't matter which framework you use. Those solutions apply to any framework, let it be Laravel, Symfony, Zend, you name it.

Comment: @emix I did work with the older version of laravel but I did face this issue only with 5.8

Comment: Can you please show directory structure ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro Thanks for asking but i got my solution

Comment: Could you please tell us how did you managed to resolve it, it will help us learn :)

Comment: Check this link https://gist.github.com/Guley/6b114d33eb7420a0a07d58670d965a8c and i also added answer related to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got the solution. Thanks for your help.

In order to use mod_rewrite you can type the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart apache2 after

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Here is root directory .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have `mod_rewrite` enable on your Apache server. The rewrite module is required to apply these settings. You also have enabled `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```