# Remove index.php from url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have removed index.php from a url using following code but if i type ww.mywebsite.com/index.php then with this url also it is working but i want to remove index.php if user types index.php in
between the url. This is my code of .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: please chek this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url

Comment: Already some people solved this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**Option 1**
Point public folder directly in host file

```
<Project Path>/public
```

**Option 2**

1. created 1 folder `protected` in project root
2. all folder and file move to protected folder except public
3. all public folder & files move to root folder
4. and change include path in public/index.php

   `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
   require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

to

```
require __DIR__.'/protected/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/protected/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: It is redirecting to mywebsite.com/public

Comment: but i have to remove it from url

Comment: if possible change in host file like  `<project-path>/public`

Comment: answer updated  please check and you can set any name in your protected folder

Answer (score 0):

For .htaccess you can try this -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]  // path to your public directory
</IfModule>
```

or

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/(.*)index\.php\sHTTP.*$
  RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hop one of them will work.

Comment: Have you changed path of system MVC or public folders?