# Laravel how to remove 'public' in url (version 7)

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

[up media](https://upmedia.ir/) my website root link

But it also works with the following link

https: // upmedia.ir/ public

***What should I do to not open the site with the address / public?***

**my public/.htaccess codes**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**my main dir .htaccess codes**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

```
</IfModule>
<IfModule lsapi_module>
```

Comment: what you can do is move your whole project except public one dir back `../` and all the contents inside public should be there in the root directory, that's how you can remove public or instead you can mark public as root in your domain.conf file.

Comment: you can set public root  ex: DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yourprojectfoldername/public

Comment: I do not want to do this, do not have a better solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Can I Remove “public/index.php” in the URL Generated Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Set the public folder as the root of your website.

Comment: I do not want to do this, do not have a better solution?